# How to make sure there are no excessive commas

Tags: php, string

I have a `$string` containing `1,9,56,566`, by using `str_replace()` I can remove a number from that string, but if I remove for example `56` then `$string` will contain `1,9,,566` and if I remove `1` then `$string` will be `,9,56,566` instead and so on.

So how can I make sure that no matter what number I remove, that there never is a comma at the start or at the end and that there never is more than 1 comma in a row between numbers?

```
$result = str_replace($numberToRemove, '', $string);
```

Comment: `$result = trim(str_replace([',,',',,,'], ',', $string),',');` one way to rome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim(preg_replace('/,,+/', ',', ',1,,9,56,,,,,566,'),',')` as the final adjustment -> it takes care of leading and trailing comma as well as of multiple commas.

However, when doing the replace you have to take into account the possibility of having same numbers in the string. In your example it would be 56.

With str_replace for 56 the result is `1,9,,6`. I would guess that the desired result is `1,9,,566`. If that is the case, you probably need preg_replace again: `preg_replace('/(^|,)56(,|$)/', ',', '1,9,56,566')`. It removes the number only if it is enclosed in commas or it is on the begining/end of string.

For clarity lets do it step by step:

```
$starting_string = '1,9,56,566';
$number_to_remove = '56';
$result = preg_replace('/(^|,)'.$number_to_remove.'(,|$)/', ',', $starting_string);
$result = preg_replace('/,,+/', ',', $result);
$result = trim($result, ',');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the number in the string, explode the string into an array, then implode it again ignoring the empty array items. As code example below.

```
<?php

function filterFunction($var) {
    if($var == "0" || $var != "") { return true; }
}

$string = "1,0,9,56,566";
$numberToRemove = 9;
$result = str_replace($numberToRemove, '', $string);

$resultarray = explode(",",$result);
$result = implode(",",array_filter($resultarray, "filterFunction"));


echo $result;

?>
```

EDIT: Added callback function to allow for 0's as corrected by Andy below

Comment: This strips out the number "0" because it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to do this with a longer string with potentially more numbers in it you'll want to consider possibilities where there are several commas in a row (more than just one or two).

Also, what happens if the number you're replacing occurs inside another number (for example 56 is 'inside' 566)?  My snippet doesn't consider that, but it's worth getting clarity on.

[https://3v4l.org/pOP0p](https://3v4l.org/Lqjhf)

```
<?php    
$numbers = ',,,1,56,0,32,9,56,566';
$numberToRemove = 56;
$removed = str_replace($numberToRemove, '', $numbers);
$kaPow = explode(',', $removed);
$kaPow = array_filter( $kaPow, 'strlen' );
echo implode(',', $kaPow);
```

Comment: Never thought of 56 being in 566. Maybe if you compared the length of the numbers and only deleted the one that has the same amount? That way 56 wouldn't get deleted in 566

Comment: I think you're right, just code a callback for array_filter that matches the element to what you want to remove and drop str_replace entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace` instead to remove the comma at the same time.

```
$string = preg_replace("/(^{$numberToRemove},|,{$numberToRemove}\b)/", '', $string);
```

In the pattern, `^{$numberToRemove},` matches the number and trailing comma at the beginning of the string, and `,{$numberToRemove}\b` matches the leading comma and number in the middle or at the end of the string.

---

If you're going to use array conversion as part of the solution, it's probably better to convert the string to an array *before* doing the replacement and remove the number from the array instead of using `str_replace` and  trying to deal with leftover commas.

```
$numbers = explode(',', $string);

array_filter($numbers, function ($n) use ($numberToRemove) {
    return $n != $numberToRemove;
});

$string = implode(',', $numbers);
```

Comment: Using this I can't remove the last number of the string for some reason.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, I just realized my error. I'm about to edit the answer.

Comment: @P.Nick Okay, it should work for each (beginning/end/middle) case now.

Answer (score 1):

Append a comma to the numberToRemove, append a comma to the search string and then trim any trailing comma. If you start with a clean one comma between values string, you should end up the same.

```
$result = trim(str_replace($numberToRemove.',', '', $string.','), ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

delete your number
then ltrim http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ltrim.php
and then str_replace ',,' by ','

Comment: it will if you ltrim the comma as i said

Comment: @OGenthe no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very simple string replace, not using the array functions that should catch every scenario based on your question.

```
//this will remove the number with left comma
$numberwithleftcommaToRemove=",".$numberToRemove;
$result = str_replace($numberwithleftcommaToRemove, '', $string);
//if there was no left comma, this will remove the number with right comma
$numberwithrightcommaToRemove=$numberToRemove.",";
$result = str_replace($numberwithrightcommaToRemove, '', $string);
```